# jQuery homepage slider images are visibly darker in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, png

So I'm working on this custom slider for this new site. I've got two separate functions running. One controls the background slides and one controls the text and text background images.

The animation runs fine in the big 5 browsers but IE (testing on version 8 here) for some reason displays the images very dark for some reason. Firefox (5), Safari (5), and Chrome all display properly.

Anyone have any thoughts?

You can find the slider here:
www.bigideaadv.com/a-z

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using PNGs, which, when coupled with jquery and IE, produce poor results (typically turning transparency black), stemming from IEs AlphaLoader implementation. Guessing its your large circular graphics.

There are a number of [PNG fixes available](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iepngfix), but I have found them generally finicky at best. Though the problems are largely ie6 and ie7 based, I've experienced issues up through 8.

Update =
given your valiant attempt to convince IE to do what you want it to, why not just write two scripts (as you already have), and give users with decent browswers a better experience?

Comment: Hmmm, I've exhausted all of those .png fix options, even trying to edit the .png file data with that TweakPNG program. No dice.

Could there be another possible solution?

Comment: Make a Flash fallback for IE... :D Seriously, I've wasted many hours trying to figure out similar issues, with no solution. I'm almost 100% certain that the png issue is your problem, and there may be no good workaround, save the png fixes you tried already. I'd love to be proven wrong, however. In the near / distant future, we can look to the canvas tag, css3 transitions, or svg animations to accomplish what your working on... but those are all poorly supported today.

Comment: Thanks for insight Bosworth99. We gave up on the triple layered animation and took it down to just the background and one overlayed png. It works for what we want to do just doesn't look as pretty.

Comment: Crap! It was looking pretty good, sad that you have to compromise. Whats really sad is that IE can't get its shit together on a clearly VERY POPULAR js framework and file type...

Comment: Hell Apple is becoming very much like IE. Doing what they want just because they can. Although Apple's reasoning is a lot better than, "Screw it. Our user base is pretty dumb, they don't need a safe, secure browser that renders code standards correctly. Let the smart, web designers and programmers figure all that out."